# Endpoint Data to AlertDialog - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

i'm trying to show through an AlertDialog element the terms and condition of usage for my application, this text is stored into an EndPoint, the connection is made in the ApiInterface.kt and looks like this

```
    // Método para obtener los terminos y condiciones de uso
        @GET("/{terms}")
        suspend fun getTyc(
            @Path("bodymetric360/terms") terminos: String,
            @Header("X-API-KEY") apiKey: String
        ): Response<TermsApiResponse>
    }
```

I would like to know how can i show the title and the description in the AlertDialog (that will be activated with an icon)